# I want two legends for same graph. In the example given, I want two legends for red and blue color bars

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

```
`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 x_axis=['blah','blahs','yeah']
 y_axis=[10,20,30]
 col=['blue' if i<=10 else'red' for i in y_axis]
 plt.bar(x_axis,y_axis,color=col]`
```

<Here x_axis and y_axis are the axis of graph, have two different color bars. How to give legends for that two colors?>

Comment: you want graph as line or marker to points ?

Comment: I want Bar graph

Answer (score 1):

you have to create custom in `legend` function example like

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x_axis=['blah','blahs','yeah']
y_axis=[10,20,30]

col=['blue' if i<=10 else'red' for i in y_axis]

plt.bar(x_axis,y_axis,color=col)

colors = {'less than 10 group':'blue', 'greater than 10 group':'red'}         
labels = list(colors.keys())
handles = [plt.Rectangle((0,0),1,2, color=colors[label]) for label in labels] # it is legend design like rectangle

plt.legend(handles, labels) 
plt.show()
```

see the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html)